# Sticky nav's background won't activate at the right point after an image slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a sticky nav and I want the background color of white to activate after the user scrolls past the image slider—basically I want the white background of the nav to appear in the orange logos section. Currently I have the white background of the nav being called at a specific point through the class ".getsticky" with jquery. The class is being applied to the orange logo section but because the image slider calls hidden images the nav background appears above the image slider and not the orange logo section. I tried placing a negative pixel offset on the jquery event but the issue is I've build a percentage based responsive site so the pixel offset doesn't really work for all the different browser sizes. Any thought on how to correct this would be great!

thanks!

If you want to see this in action. here is the website I'm working on http://www.schipperbros.com

below you can see the jquery for calling the background color as well as where the ".getsticky" class is applied in the HTML

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    if ( $(window).width() > 769) {     
       var scroll_start = 0;
       var startchange = $('.getsticky');
       var offset = startchange.offset();
       $(document).scroll(function() { 
          scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop() + 0;
          // scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
          if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
              $('.main-nav').css('background-color','rgba(255,255,255,0.8)');
           } else {
              $('.main-nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
           }
       });
    }
 });









<div id="work" class="grid twelve work">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/work/photo1.jpg" /></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <img src="img/work/photo2.jpg" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <img src="img/work/photo3.jpg" />

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="grid work-logos getsticky">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="grid twelve">                   
                <div>
                    <p>
                        Select clients from our collective experience.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid twelve logoSquare">
                <div class="grid threeDesktop threeTablet fourPhone six">
                    <img src="img/about/ibm_logo.svg" alt="IBM">
                </div>
                <div class="grid threeDesktop threeTablet fourPhone six">
                    <img src="img/about/google_logo.svg" alt="Google">
                </div>
                <div class="grid threeDesktop threeTablet fourPhone six">
                    <img src="img/about/aiga_logo.svg" alt="AIGA">
                </div>
                <div class="grid threeDesktop threeTablet fourPhone six">
                    <img src="img/about/obama_logo.svg" alt="Obama">
                </div>
                <div class="grid threeDesktop threeTablet fourPhone six">
                    <img src="img/about/espn_logo.svg" alt="ESPN">
                </div>
                <div class="grid threeDesktop threeTablet fourPhone six">
                    <img src="img/about/herman_logo.svg" alt="Herman">
                </div>
                <div class="grid threeDesktop threeTablet fourPhone six">
                    <img src="img/about/vaystays_logo.svg" alt="Vaystays">
                </div>
                <div class="grid threeDesktop threeTablet fourPhone six">
                    <img src="img/about/nd_logo.svg" alt="ND">
                </div>
                <div class="grid threeDesktop threeTablet fourPhone six">
                    <img src="img/about/sd_logo.svg" alt="SD">
                </div>
                <div class="grid threeDesktop threeTablet fourPhone six">
                    <img src="img/about/fuzzy_logo.svg" alt="Fuzzy">
                </div>
                <div class="grid threeDesktop threeTablet fourPhone six">
                    <img src="img/about/usaa_logo.svg" alt="USAA">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that jQuery is getting offset value at the wrong time.

You can set offset again inside `$(document).scroll` and it will work.
The new function will be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    if ( $(window).width() > 769) {     
       var scroll_start = 0;
       var startchange = $('.getsticky');
       var offset = startchange.offset();
       $(document).scroll(function() { 
          scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop() + 0;

          offset = startchange.offset(); // ADDED THIS LINE !!

          // scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
          if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
              $('.main-nav').css('background-color','rgba(255,255,255,0.8)');
           } else {
              $('.main-nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
           }
       });
    }
 });
```